# How to give general path while comparing data between two sheets in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

When I compare **data** using **Microsoft Query** in Microsoft Excel to compare sheets it takes c:\user\mgow\desktop\Excel.xlsm path to compare. But when I use this Excel.xlsm file on others system I see the error (odbc excel driver login failed). Can anyone help to overcome this issue.

Note: I don't want to use specific path C:\Users\mgow\Desktop\Excel.xlsm
Can I use common path which everyone can use ?

```
Sub Macro()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Users\mgow\Desktop\Excel.xlsm;DefaultDir=C:\Users\mgow\Desktop\" _
        ), Array("RAM;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination _
        :=Range("$B$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT `Result$`.REQUIREMENTS, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA1`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA2`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA3`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA4`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA5`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DAT" _
        , _
        "A6`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA7`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA8`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA9`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA10`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA11`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA12`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA13`, `Result$`.`AUDIT" _
        , _
        " DATA14`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA15`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA16`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA17`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA18`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA19`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA20`, `Result$`.`AUDIT DATA21`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `Co" _
        , _
        "mpare$` `Compare$`, `Result$` `Result$`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE `Result$`.REQUIREMENTS = `Compare$`.REQUIREMENTS" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Excel_Files"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have macro code which doesn't work then you should post that code as part of your question, along with an exact description of the error and which line it occurs on.

Comment: What would be a "common path which everyone can use" ?  Do you mean a network share?

Comment: If I send my excel sheet to someone, they should be able to access this comparison feature without using my path (C:\Users\mgow\Desktop\Excel.xlsm). Use excel sheet only to compare, irrespective of the location where the document is saved.

Comment: Is your code in the same Excel file as the one being queried, or is your data in a separate file from the macro ?

Comment: My code is saved in the same excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the place/path where a workbook is stored you can use

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```